# Update Knockout Observable and Dropdown Select

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I have an ASPX page with a dropdown select bound with Knockout.JS. On the page load I check the url for a parameter and update the view if their is a parameter which you can see in my API. I've changed the API to leave out unnecessary code because it returns the value needed. My problem is that I cannot get my observable SelectedView to update to "Notes". Any advice?

ASPX:

```
       <asp:DropDownList runat="server" data-bind="value: SelectedView" id="viewselect">
           <asp:ListItem>Select A View</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>Notes</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>Credit Manager</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
```

View Model:

```
function CustomerViewModel() {

    this.self = this;
    self.SelectedCustomer = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedView = ko.observable();
}
```

API:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 var custnmbr = "123456";

 if (custnmbr != "") {
     var notes = "Notes";
     self.SelectedView(notes);
 }

});
```

Comment: Can you please post the result rendered HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you look in console you 'll get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'SelectedView'
```

Because in your `$(document).ready` you are using the object `self` which is only defined inside `CustomerViewModel()`.

To solve this, you need to call `.SelectedView(notes);` on the object instance you are passing to `ko.applyBindings`,

***UPDATE***

for example:

```
function CustomerViewModel() {
    this.self = this;
    self.SelectedCustomer = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedView = ko.observable();
}
var customerObj=new CustomerViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(customerObj);

// later in your code.
customerObj.SelectedView(notes);
```

Comment: Okay . . . I return this
    return ko.applyBindings(new CustomerViewModel.SelectedView(notes));  

but now I get the Console Error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: how are you suggesting to call .SelectedView(notes)